# How Do I Specify the Exact Point of My Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to draw a panel in my windows form application but it always appear on the top right corner of the application when i start the application.

How do I specify the points or what is the code to specify the points of whereby the panel appear at my desired spot of my Windows Form Application.

Here is a small sample code of my flowlayoutpanel

```
var nFlowPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel 
        { 
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill, 
            FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown,
            WrapContents = false,
            AutoScroll = true
        };

nFlowPanel.Controls.Add(createNotificationPanel());

this.Controls.Add(nFlowPanel);
```

and this is the code for my panel

```
var p = new Panel 
        {

        };

p.Controls.Add(new Button { Text = "Test" });

return p;
```

as this will always appear on the top right corner of my application.

How do i write the code to specify the exact location of where i want it to be?

Another question is also how do i set the location of the button within the panel to appear in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ironically, to set the Location of a control, you use the Location property.

```
var p = new Panel();
p.Location = new Point(100, 100);
```

and for the button:

```
p.Controls.Add(new Button { Text = "Test", Location = new Point(32, 32)});
```

If you are asking to place the controls in an exact location inside the `FlowLayoutPanel`, well, then you don't want to use a `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I am referring is how do i shift the position of my flowlayoutpanel to another part of my application. i understood the part for the location of the panel but as i use nFlowPanel.Location = new Point(500,500); , it still starts up at the top right corner of my application.